# Recursive React component for deep nested data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to convert JSON data with deep nesting as follows

**Data**

```
[
    {
        _id: 1,
        name: 'name',
        children: [...]
    },
];
```

**React Component**

```
import React from 'react';

const TableRow = ({ standard }) => {
    if (standard.children && standard.children.length === 0) {
        return <p>Children-{standard.name}</p>;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <p>Parent-{standard.name}</p>
            {standard.children &&
                standard.children.length &&
                standard.children.map((child, i) => (
                    <>
                         <TableRow
                            key={`${child._id}`}
                            standard={child}
                        /> 
                    </>
                ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default TableRow;
```

**Parent Component**

```
{updatedStandards.map((standard) => (
    <TableRow key={standard._id} standard={standard} />
))}
```

While running the component the browser freezes ...

Comment: Do you have any useEffect or something in the parent or child?

Comment: Could there be a parent that is also a child further down the road? That would create a cycle. (Though it's impossible if it's JSON)

Comment: Since your browser freezes, there's definitly an inifnite loop going on here, so try to see why React doesn't "stop" rendering TableRow at some point.

My guess is that `standard.children && standard.children.length === 0` does not happen for some reason ... a little hard to "guess" from here

Comment: The parent has useEffect to get the data from an API @JoseRojas